# YouTrack JavaScript Workflow - send email to global group

Tags: youtrack

I am creating a state machine for YouTrack using JavaScript, and am trying to send an email to everyone in a group. In the old Workflows, this was done like this:

```
{group:PHP Developers}.notifyAllUsers("Subject","message");
```

I can't find anything in the new JavaScript API to do this, where can I find the global (not issue or project) groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS API it will look as follows:

`entities.UserGroup.findByName('PHP Developers')
    .notifyAllUsers('Subject','message');`

However, another (and way more reliable) way to get a particular user group is to add it to requirements and the reference inside the code:

`ctx.phpdevs.notifyAllUsers('Subject','message');
...
requirements: {
  ...
  phpDevs: {
    type: entities.UserGroup,
    name: 'PHP Developers' 
  }
}`

You may find more details in official documentation: [UserGroup](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/v1-UserGroup.html) and [Finding Specific Entities](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/using-workflow-api.html#find-specific-entities).